# Pandas dataframe.replace()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Let say I have a table with 5 column. 2-3 column inside the row contain "Not reported".

I want to drop the row that contain with "Not reported". I change the value with "Not reported" to NaN and using the dropna() method to drop it.

```
import pandas as pd 
  
df = pd.read_csv("report.csv") 
df.replace(to_replace = np.nan, value ='Not reported') 
df.dropna(inplace= True)  #method 1

temp=['age','sex','country']
df[temp]= df[temp].replace('Not reported', np.NAN)
df.dropna(inplace= True) #method 2
```

I want to know is what are the difference between this 2 method?

Answer (score 1):

In Method 1, you are checking for the value "Not reported" in the entire data frame.

However, in Method 2 you are doing the same thing, but on only the 3 selected columns in `temp`.

Method 2 can be preferred, it should be faster.

Comment: Meaning to say there is no right or wrong using this 2 method right?